# Drive Formatting - Not Operational

Tags: partitioning, usb, mount

I have a [Sandisk Wireless USB Stick](https://www.amazon.com.au/SanDisk-128GB-Connect-Wireless-Android/dp/B00ZCFYFAO), that has data stored on it. Whether Arch, Debian or Ubuntu I am unable to format the  unit. Firstly, I attempted `gparted` to attempt to format the device (`/dev/sdc`) however upon performing the action (and being flagged as "successful") the content of the USB remains.

When I look at `blkid` I get the following information:

```
   /dev/sdc1: SEC_TYPE="msdos" UUID="833C-CDB0" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="0dfab3a5-01"
   /dev/sdc2: LABEL="NEW VOLUME" UUID="523E-7BD9" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="0dfab3a5-02"
```

Further to this I attempted `dd` the disk to get an outcome, but I still get the above behaviour of files magically returning:

```
home# dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sdc bs=1M
```

Within GNOME Disks, I see 9.2GB worth of data consumed. I am starting to suspect some issue with the USB, but wanted to see if there are any other tools Ubuntu has to offer for disk managememt/formatting.

Comment: Are you sure that the stick is compatible with Linux? Have you tested it in Windows or MacOS or Android?

Comment: I have now confirmed on other OS that the same fault occurs.

Comment: Then there may be a severe problem, 'gridlock', which is a first stage of complete failure. This means that the drive is read-only, and the next step is that it will be totally dead. You had better save any files, that you might want to keep, while it can still be read. You can also analyze the problem, and if you are lucky solve it according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035).